# Plot bifurcation diagram from time series chaotic data

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

I have equations for Chua's circuit and need to plot bifurcation diagram.

From the things I have read so far, I need to use 1-dimensional map to get the bifurcation diagram, but I have trouble understanding how I can transform my times series data using a map for plotting the bifurcation diagram.

I would appreciate your help a lot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one parameter it is ease to make [bifurcation diagram](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_of_real_numbers/r_iterations).

If you have more then one parameter, maybe choose a path inside parameter plane ( or space) and check what happens along this path.
 [image]

If your points are 3D  then you need more dimensions to visualise bifurcation, so make animations of your [3D plots](http://www.chuacircuits.com/matlabsim.php). Then you will have 4d diagram.

HTH